# Limit of sequence induced by dilation of Lebesgue integrable function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f$ be Lebesgue integrable and continuous in a bounded domain $\Omega$ in $\mathbb{R}
^n$, and define $f_m(x)=f(\frac{m}{m+1}x).$ Then $f_m(x)$ converges pointwise to $f(x)$ for $x\in \Omega.$ I was wondering if it is true $\int_\Omega f_m(x)dx \to \int_\Omega f(x)dx$ as $m\to\infty$, without additional assumption on $f$.

Note that if $f$ is bounded, we can easily show it in view of Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem.

Please let me know if you have any hint or comment for the question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I added the assumption that $f$ is continuous. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: There's no reason to think that $f_m$ is well-defined.

Comment: @zhw. You’re right. If $Omega$ is an open ball, it can be easily modified, but it is not true for general domain. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy to show that  $\int_\Omega f_m\to\int_\Omega f$ for every $f\in L^1(\Bbb R^n)$, in fact $||f_m-f||_1\to0$. Let $\epsilon>0$. Choose $g\in C_c(\Bbb R^n)$ with $||f-g||_1<\epsilon$...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don’t understand it. Why you assume $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$? Please give me more hint.

Comment: Assuming $f\in L^1(\Bbb R^n)$ is assuming much less than you assumed! The point is you don't need to assume $f$ is continuous.

Comment: How about $f_m$ defined above? I’d like to know the relation with $f$ and $f_m.$

Comment: ??? The relation between $f$ and $f_m$ is $f_m(x)=f(\frac{m}{m+1}x).$ Why would you think anything else?

Comment: Sorry! I still don’t understand your answer. You choose specific $g$ satisfying $\|f-g\|<\epsilon.$ Then what can I do next? Should I define $g_m$ satisfying similar property with $f_m$?

Comment: $||f-f_m||_1\le||f-g||_1+||g-g_m||_1+||g_m-f_m||_1=\left(1+\left(\frac{m+1}m\right)^n\right)||f-g||_1+||g-g_m||_1$.